# Gray square around disabled radio button

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

[buttons on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUg5h.png)I have created radio buttons in ASP.NET using bootstrap.  These buttons are supposed to be disabled which works fine in chrome but in Internet explorer, it creates a gray square around the buttons.  I've been able to get it removed on IE by wrapping the input tag with a div disabled tag.  However, this does not work in chrome.  So I can't get one to work without messing up the other.  The code I have included is the one that works with chrome.

```css
input[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
       <input disabled="disabled" checked="checked" class="form-check-input" id="Male" name="GenderSelection" type="radio" value="Y">
       </div>
        <label for="Male">Male</label>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJr9J.png)

Comment: Hello UniJur this appears to be a CSS issue. Could you please add your css code to your question so we can better see whats going.

Comment: Hi Charles, I added the CSS

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with the css.

```
input[disabled] {background-color:#cfcfcf;}
```

remove that and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi nkahootxShawn, please see the updated issue.  Thank you

Comment: Since I answered the original question, do you mind marking it as correct. thank you!